# dask's local scheduler and gevent

Tags: python, gevent, dask

I'm using `distributed.Client` to do some local computation. I'm also wanting to spawn a gevent greenlet from the main thread to do some unrelated monitoring. Using gevent's `patch_all()` method, will turn native threads into greenlets. Given that most of the work done by the scheduler is pandas/numpy, and thus I suspect most of it releases the GIL, native threads would be useful. I'm concerned that having them patched by gevent will be entirely sub-optimal. However not patching native threads gives me other headaches (specifically, throwing errors when the local scheduler tries to fork the Bokeh server. It's a known limitation). Is there a suggested best practice when using gevent and dask/distributed, or should it just be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask.distributed uses Tornado for concurrency while computations happen in other threads.  Both computation and communication overlap in the same process.  If you stop using proper threads then communication will block until long-running computations finish.  This can cause your workers to become unresponsive because they must wait on long-running computations before they're able to handle communication requests with other workers.  The fact that numpy/pandas computations release the GIL is only helpful if you're actually using threads.

If forking off the bokeh server is an issue you might also choose to just not use the bokeh web server with the `--no-bokeh` flag.

```
dask-scheduler --no-bokeh
```

Or, in short, dask.distributed is not tested with gevent and has no plans to support it.

Comment: Right, that's why I want to be using pthreads and not greenlets. Given the blocking nature of CPU bound processes, and the fact that child processes will inherit a copy of the greenlets I decided to throw away that whole approach. I can't think of a sensible way to use dask and gevent together.